# Android : How to get only last sent sms in outbox?

Tags: android, sms, android-contentprovider, android-cursor

Trying to get last SMS from content provider using this way.

```
@Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
        String selection = "type = '2'"; //Selection parameter to only select messages in sent folder
        // save the message to the SD card here
        Logger.d("On Change");
        Toast.makeText(mCtx,"TEST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Cursor cur = mCtx.getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, selection,
                null, null);
        String body = null;

        if(cur.moveToFirst()){
            body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
            Logger.d(body);
            cur.close();
        }
```

But i always getting last **TWO MESSAGES FROM OUTBOX**, but i want the only last.

How should i do it in the right way please?

**EDIT:**

Log after send message with text "TWO":

```
01-09 16:10:27.205 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
01-09 16:10:27.205 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ║ Thread: main
01-09 16:10:27.205 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ╟────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
01-09 16:10:27.205 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ║ ContentObserver.onChange  (ContentObserver.java:129)
01-09 16:10:27.205 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ║    SMSoutObserver.onChange  (SMSoutObserver.java:46)
01-09 16:10:27.205 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ╟────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
01-09 16:10:27.205 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ║ On Change
01-09 16:10:27.205 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
01-09 16:10:27.245 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
01-09 16:10:27.245 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ║ Thread: main
01-09 16:10:27.245 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ╟────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
01-09 16:10:27.245 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ║ ContentObserver.onChange  (ContentObserver.java:129)
01-09 16:10:27.245 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ║    SMSoutObserver.onChange  (SMSoutObserver.java:54)
01-09 16:10:27.245 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ╟────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
01-09 16:10:27.245 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ║ ONE
01-09 16:10:27.245 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
01-09 16:10:27.265 1685-1685/? V/SmsReceiverService: onStart: #1 mResultCode: -1 = Activity.RESULT_OK
01-09 16:10:27.305 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
01-09 16:10:27.315 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ║ Thread: main
01-09 16:10:27.325 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ╟────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
01-09 16:10:27.325 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ║ ContentObserver.onChange  (ContentObserver.java:129)
01-09 16:10:27.325 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ║    SMSoutObserver.onChange  (SMSoutObserver.java:46)
01-09 16:10:27.325 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ╟────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
01-09 16:10:27.325 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ║ On Change
01-09 16:10:27.325 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
01-09 16:10:27.325 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
01-09 16:10:27.325 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ║ Thread: main
01-09 16:10:27.325 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ╟────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
01-09 16:10:27.325 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ║ ContentObserver.onChange  (ContentObserver.java:129)
01-09 16:10:27.325 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ║    SMSoutObserver.onChange  (SMSoutObserver.java:54)
01-09 16:10:27.335 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ╟────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
01-09 16:10:27.335 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ║ ONE
01-09 16:10:27.335 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
01-09 16:10:27.335 1685-1685/? V/SmsReceiverService: onStart: #1 mResultCode: -1 = Activity.RESULT_OK
01-09 16:10:27.355 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
01-09 16:10:27.355 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ║ Thread: main
01-09 16:10:27.355 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ╟────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
01-09 16:10:27.355 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ║ ContentObserver.onChange  (ContentObserver.java:129)
01-09 16:10:27.355 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ║    SMSoutObserver.onChange  (SMSoutObserver.java:46)
01-09 16:10:27.355 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ╟────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
01-09 16:10:27.355 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ║ On Change
01-09 16:10:27.355 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
01-09 16:10:27.355 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
01-09 16:10:27.355 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ║ Thread: main
01-09 16:10:27.355 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ╟────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
01-09 16:10:27.355 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ║ ContentObserver.onChange  (ContentObserver.java:129)
01-09 16:10:27.355 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ║    SMSoutObserver.onChange  (SMSoutObserver.java:54)
01-09 16:10:27.355 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ╟────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
01-09 16:10:27.355 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ║ TWO
01-09 16:10:27.355 4230-4230/? D/PRETTYLOGGER: ╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>You can set the last argument in the `query()` call to `"date DESC LIMIT 1"`, but this might not work everywhere.</s>

I misunderstood the question, which was resolved in comments, so I'll edit the relevant portions into the answer for reference.

When an SMS message is sent using the platform SMS app - as well as many third-party SMS clients - it goes through a few steps that involve "moving" the message around in the Provider. First it gets written to the queue, then moved to the outbox, and finally to the sent box (if successful). The Provider does this by changing the value of the message's `type` column, and your Observer's `onChange()` method is going to fire each time that happens. Since the posted code is querying for only sent messages, the first two times `onChange()` fires, the previously sent message is returned, rather than the current message, as the current will have `type` `6`, and then `4` for the first two "moves".

The solution is to change the query to omit the `selection` by passing null, which will cause the first message in the returned `Cursor` to be the last message updated. We then check the `type` column for a value of `2`, indicating that the message has been successfully sent, and we can then process it as needed.

Comment: I'm assuming this is a follow-up to your last question, and you still want the sort order like that. I'd also left my last answer's query rather broad, just because this might fail on some implementations.

Comment: String selection = "date DESC LIMIT 1 && type = '2'" Not working.

Comment: No, the last argument in the `query()` call, not the selection: `query(uriSMSURI, null, selection, null, "date DESC LIMIT 1");`.

Comment: Thanks, but 2 last messages are still returned.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean by returning 2. What's happening is that `onChange()` is going to fire for every change made to the Provider. The way the Provider handles "moving" messages from, say, the outbox to the sent box, is by changing the `type` column for a message. So, the first time it fires, it's because the current message is being written to the outbox, so your query will return the last sent message before the current one. Then, when it moves the current message from the outbox to the sent box, it fires again, but this time the current message is the last one with `type` `2`. Follow me?

Comment: Yes, it is right. OnChange is triggered twice. But change tocontent://sms/outbox is triggering two times too.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean. Could you post your logs?

Comment: Oh, wait, I think I know what you mean. For a send, `onChange()` will actually fire three times. The very first one is writing to `raw`, I believe. Then the move to the `outbox`, then to `sent`.

Comment: Yes, i added log to question. Do You know how to solve it please?

Comment: That's kinda why I structured the code like I did in my previous answer. Query without the selection, get the very last message change in descending order by date (adding the `LIMIT`, if desired), and if it's not `type` `2`, then ignoring it. So, like `query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, "date DESC LIMIT 1");`, then check the `type`, and ignore if it's not `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved using :

```
Cursor cur = mCtx.getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null,
                null, "date DESC LIMIT 1");
        String body = null;

        if(cur.moveToFirst()){
            String messageType = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type")).toString();
            if(messageType.equals("2")) { //2 == type sent
                String type = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type")).toString();
                body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
                Logger.d(body);
                Logger.d(type);
            }

        }
        cur.close();
```

Thanks to Mike for his advice.